# Passing information to an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like users to be able to fill in two text fields and when they click the submit button, those two pieces of information (in this case postcodes) will have been pre-filled out on a form.

You can see an example that works here:
https://www.reallymoving.com/first-time-buyers

The trouble is that in my case it will be going to an iframe.

Which you can see in action here:
http://www.wacdesign.com/pps/rc/compare.html

But is it possible to pass information from a form on the previous page over to this larger form?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a little beyond me @Wojciech Sobczyk though I appreacite you taking the time to try and help. Hopefuly it will be of more use to someone else.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wacdesign/gsU7Q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form when you set method="GET" and submit it will add parameters to the address in form of ?param1=value1&param2=value2

this parameters you can read on the server befor rendering the page
Ie in php:

$param1 = $_GET["param1"];

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use a GET, passing the form parameters in the URL to your app.

e.g.

```
http://www.wacdesign.com/pps/rc/compare.html?form1=value1&form2=value2
```

This would provide "value1" in the form1 parameter and "value2" in the form2 parameter, which you can then parse in your app.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still a little in the dark as this isn't my strong point so I'm hoping you can really spell it out for me.

So if I have this (for example)
<input type="text" id="form1">
<input type="text" id="form2">
<input type="button" value="submit">

and wanted the two text fields to fill the two postcodes sections of this: http://www.reallymoving.com/quote-forms/removals.aspx?refID=NHFS_rem&mode=narrow

Comment: I think wojciech-sobczyk summarized it fairly well.  How you access those parameters depends on the programming language you're using, of course.